# Angular Scope data is not refreshing in Select box in IE 9, and it choked in it even when we are removing it from

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-9

Hello I am using the below code to change the Select box values, this code is perfectly working as expected in Chrome and Mozila, but I having issue in IE 9 Browser only.

Problem:
1 .>freeSelect Method should remove all the values from the selected option, but when I run this html in IE 9, even though it remove it from select box, but when you click on the select box to see any option are there or not, it will show it, but you can not select, I do not know the reason.
2.> addValue method will add the option value in the selected box, but here what is happening, this select box also showing the old values, which you can not select it.

This is my script below:

```
 var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);
 phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.mydata = [
            {
                    id:"0",
                    dataTxt:"1",
                    selectOption: [{optionss:"--Please Select--"},{optionss:"val11"},{optionss:"val12"}],
                    selectedData:"--Please Select--",
                    },
                    { id:"1",
                        dataTxt:"2",
                        selectOption: [{optionss:"--Please Select--"},{optionss:"val21"},{optionss:"val22"}],
                        selectedData:"--Please Select--",
                    }
                ];

$scope.freeSelect=function(id){
      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.mydata));
  alert($scope.mydata[id].selectedData)
  $scope.mydata[id].selectOption=[];
  $scope.mydata[id].selectedData="";
  console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.mydata));
 // $scope.$apply($scope.mydata);
```

}

```
$scope.addValue=function(id){
      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.mydata));
      $scope.mydata[id].selectOption=[{optionss:"--Please Select--"},  {optionss:"val11"}];
      $scope.mydata[id].selectedData="--Please Select--";
      console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.mydata));
  }
 $scope.getData=function(id){
    alert($scope.mydata[id].selectedData)
}
```

```
     <table  class="table" data-ng-controller="PhoneListCtrl" id="tbl" style="margin-top:-30px; width: 1380px">
        <tr><th>Data</th><th>Data2</th><th>button</th></tr>
        <tr data-ng-repeat="record in mydata" id="{{'tr'+record.id}}" style="color:#FF0000;">
          <td><input type="text" data-ng-model="record.dataTxt"/></td>
        <td>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" data-ng-model="record.selectedData"  data-ng-change="getData(record.id)"  id="{{record.id}}"> 
            <option data-ng-repeat="options in record.selectOption"  value="{{options.optionss}}">{{options.optionss}}</option>
        </select>
   </td><td>
   <input type="button" data-ng-click="freeSelect(record.id)" value="myData"/>
    <input type=button data-ng-click="addValue(record.id)" value="addValue"/>
   </td></tr>

     </table>
```

Comment: Can you create a plunkr to ilustrate the problem?

Comment: I have created a plunker , to test this please use IE 9, becuause I am facing issue in IE 9 only .  http://plnkr.co/edit/k7kGZ88eeJPcWbbN5Lq3?p=preview

Comment: Can any one suggest what went wrong here...

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/#!/hQUFBzWLuyiTtSZTW1Qt?p=preview - does this work for you ? I can't really test in IE9